# How to delay bind mount until docker compose volume is initially populated?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have the following compose file, based on the one from [the Bitnami WordPress container image documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/wordpress/):

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:10.11.2
    volumes:
      - 'mariadb_data:/bitnami/mariadb'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MARIADB_USER=bn_wordpress
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=bitnami_wordpress
  wordpress:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/wordpress:6.2.0-debian-11-r14
    ports:
      - '80:8080'
      - '443:8443'
    volumes:
      - 'wordpress_data:/bitnami/wordpress'
      - './:/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/themes/my-theme'
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - WORDPRESS_DATABASE_HOST=mariadb
      - WORDPRESS_DATABASE_PORT_NUMBER=3306
      - WORDPRESS_DATABASE_USER=bn_wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DATABASE_NAME=bitnami_wordpress
volumes:
  mariadb_data:
    driver: local
  wordpress_data:
    driver: local
```

I want to have my compose file in my project folder and mount that same folder to `/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/themes/my-theme`, so WordPress can use my project as a theme. However, this causes an issue on the first run of `docker-compose up`…

---

As you may know from [the Docker documentation about volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container):

> If you start a container which creates a new volume, and the container has files or directories in the directory to be mounted such as `/app/`, Docker copies the directory's contents into the volume.

This is exactly what I want — to have the WordPress system files copied from the container, so they exist in the volume and the whole thing can work. However, the first time I run `docker-compose up` (when the volumes don't exist yet), I get the following error:

```
my-project-wordpress-1  | Error: 'wp-config.php' not found.
my-project-wordpress-1  | Either create one manually or use `wp config create`.
my-project-wordpress-1 exited with code 1
```

This makes sense because the bind mount is pointed to `/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/themes/my-theme`, and the volume is mounted on `/bitnami/wordpress`. Therefore, on the first run, the volume is no longer empty (because the bind mount is there) and Docker doesn't copy the files from the container to the volume, as it normally would.

If I remove the created volumes and containers and comment out this line:

```yaml
- './:/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/themes/my-theme'
```

…I can run `docker-compose up` and everything works out correctly. The only issue is that obviously, my project is not bound to the container and I can't work on it.

Now, if I kill the containers, uncomment the line above, and run `docker-compose up`, everything works because the WordPress files already exist in the volume and my bind mount doesn't interfere.

The above can be really confusing for other people who want to initialize the project:

1. You have to comment out a line in the configuration
2. Run `docker-compose up` and wait for everything to be initialized
3. Kill the containers
4. Uncomment the line
5. Run `docker-compose up` again
6. *Now* you can work on the project…

Is there a way to avoid this?

---

I tried using [`depends_on`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#depends_on) in my WordPress container and waiting for another "setup" container that is basically my main WordPress container, but without the bind mount. It didn't work out well.

Then I thought I could mark the `wordpress_data` volume as external and populate it beforehand. So instead of running `docker-compose up`, you would run a shell script that first checks if the volume exists, sets it up if it doesnt, and *then* runs `docker-compose up`. This seems too complicated…

I also thought about [extending the config](https://docs.docker.com/compose/multiple-compose-files/extends/) and having a separate "init" config without the bind mount. Then I'd have a shell script that runs the init config, waits for WordPress to be initialized, kills the containers, then runs the main config. This also seemed overly complicated…

Are there better ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this isn't the best solution, but I found a way to make it work like so:

1. Mount the bind mount to a directory outside the volume, e.g. `/theme`
2. Wait for the `/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/themes` folder to become available
3. Create a symlink of `/theme` to `/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/themes/theme`

The `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:10.11.2
    volumes:
      - 'mariadb_data:/bitnami/mariadb'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MARIADB_USER=bn_wordpress
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=bitnami_wordpress
  wordpress:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/wordpress:6.2.0-debian-11-r14
    ports:
      - '80:8080'
      - '443:8443'
    volumes:
      - './:/theme'
      - './setup.sh:/setup.sh'
      - 'wordpress_data:/bitnami/wordpress'
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - WORDPRESS_DATABASE_HOST=mariadb
      - WORDPRESS_DATABASE_PORT_NUMBER=3306
      - WORDPRESS_DATABASE_USER=bn_wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DATABASE_NAME=bitnami_wordpress
    command: sh -c "sh /setup.sh & /opt/bitnami/scripts/wordpress/entrypoint.sh /opt/bitnami/scripts/apache/run.sh"
    user: root # to be able to run setup.sh
volumes:
  mariadb_data:
    driver: local
  wordpress_data:
    driver: local
```

…and the `setup.sh` script looks like this:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
project_dir="/theme"
themes_dir="/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/themes"
symlink="$themes_dir/theme"

while true; do
  if [ -d "$themes_dir" ]; then
    [ -e "$symlink" ] && rm "$symlink"
    ln -s "$project_dir" "$symlink"
    echo "Symlinked: $symlink"
    exit 0
  else
    sleep 1
  fi
done
```

The specified `command`:

```bash
sh -c "sh /setup.sh & /opt/bitnami/scripts/wordpress/entrypoint.sh /opt/bitnami/scripts/apache/run.sh"
```

…simply creates a subshell, runs the setup script in the background, and runs [the main container script](https://github.com/bitnami/containers/blob/e58d7c4a2d0633ce440b7694fe20312d8bb4cfbb/bitnami/wordpress/6/debian-11/Dockerfile#L65-L66).

Apart from being a little weird, perhaps the biggest downside to this solution is that you need:

```yaml
user: root
```

…otherwise the setup script doesn't have sufficient permissions to create the symlink.